Azure cli command cannot find existing subscriptions
I am trying to list all private dns zones in an Azure subscription with this az cli command:
az network private-dns zone list --subscription $subscriptionName

But for some subscriptions i get this error message:
ERROR: (BadRequest) The specified subscription <SUB_ID> does not exist
Code: BadRequest
Message: The specified subscription <SUB_ID> does not exist

even though I can find the subscription in the Azure portal.
It does not happen for all subscriptions i try with the command, just a handful.
I can't find a correlation between the ones which work.
What can cause this error?

Are you looking for a way to find the private DNS zone list in multiple subscriptions or a single subscription?

In one subscription.

How are you passing the subscription name or ID? Are you doing it manually, or are you fetching the subscription name using a script?

I does not work, regardless of using the subscription name or id.

After some more digging around, it seems to be problem with the error message.
It only displays the message for subscription where no DNS zone exists.
If I call az network private-dns zone list --subscription $subscriptionName with a subscription which contains a private dns zone, no error message is displayed.

The above error was encountered due to passing incorrect subscription details in the az network private-dns zone command.
You can use the below commands to retrieve the Subscription ID without having to pass it manually.
$subname = az account subscription list
$subid =  $subname | jq -r '.[].subscriptionId'
az network private-dns zone list --subscription $subid

Output:


This does not work for me either. I have both tried with subscription name, subscription id, and subscription on the form /subscriptions/<SUB_ID>.

You can use my code for fetching subscription details and passing correct values in cmd instead of passing manually

Let me know ,If still facing an error even after using my code.
